# How to change chromium source code to modify the browser update

Tags: chromium, tchromium

I recently built a chromium browser of version 114.0.0.0 which is installed on client machine. I want to integrate a feature in chromium browser that provides the client with latest stable update of chromium browser with the changes I have made.

I monitored the behaviour of google chrome on how it updates its version. On deeper inspection I figured out google chrome checks for the latest version from their server and if there is one it downloads files and folder with the newer version and simples replaces it with the present one which is installed in the google chrome installation directory.
I basically want to customise this behaviour where I want to do the same process but from my server. How can I do it where should I change the code. Any help would be really appreciative.

Comment: This is going to be very complex and big task. Google `Google Omaha client` and `Omaha server`. You will have to integrate those products with each other. There's a consultancy firm which does that work you, Google will help you